# Call unknown constructor with unknown argument length

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I'm writing a multiplayer game server, and I'd like to load all the world data from files dynamically. These files should dynamically load an array of objects. There will be about three or four different types of objects to load from files, and there constructor argument lengths are unknown.

An example of a saved file:

```
arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4
```

Which gets split into an array

```
[arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
```

Which should then call a constructor with those arguments

```
new NPC(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

Here's the method I have right now

```
public static <T> void load(String path, Class<T> type) {
    path = dataDir + path;
    String content = Util.readFile(path);
    String[] lines = content.split("\n");
    // T[] result = new T[lines.length]; Type paramater 'T' can not be instantiated directly.
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] args = lines[i].split(", ");
        // result[i] = new T(args[0], args[1]...); Should add a T to the array with args 'args'
    }
    // return result
}
```

And it's called like this

```
Npc[] npcs = DataLoader.load("npcs.dat");
```

Comment: This is insufficient information.  What are the types of the arguments? What code have you written that instantiates the type via reflection?  What doesn't work?  To do it yourself you have to know the argument types, then use reflection to search for an appropriate constructor, then invoke it.  This is all covered in the Javadoc and various tutorials, although it's simple enough that you should be able to figure it out from the Javadoc alone.

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here. Have you checked out serialization with `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` yet?

Comment: Well, the arguments are all stored in the file as strings, so they're all possible to be converted from strings. So the only argument types will be integers and strings. Also, all of the objects only have one constructor, so I'd like to be able to find what the arguments types are, and convert the string to that type automatically.

I just finished typing this when your comment appeared Andrew, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a generic load:

```
public static <T> T[] load(String path, Class<T> type) ...
```

Declare constructors in every class taking an array of strings:

`public Npc(String[] args)` or `public Npc(String... args)`

Then use reflection to instantiate generic types:

```
// instantiate a generic array
T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, length);
// parameterized constructor of generic type, e.g. new T(String[])
Constructor<T> constructorOfT = type.getConstructor(String[].class);
// call the constructor for every position of the array
result[i] = constructorOfT.newInstance(new Object[] { args });
```

Since `load` can be called with any type or the constructor might not exit, catch reflection exceptions:

```
catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        // means caller did not call one of the supported classes (Npc)
        // or the class does not have the expected constructor
        // react in some way
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```